# How can I mirror something on a PC's display to my Android's display?

Tags: remote-access, screen-sharing

I'm currently setting up a Pivos XIOS DS as a driver for a wallboard (which is a TV mounted on a wall). Normally this is just displaying a web page with status information (currently using [Kiosk Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.automated.android.browser.kiosk&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIml0LmF1dG9tYXRlZC5hbmRyb2lkLmJyb3dzZXIua2lvc2siXQ..) for this), however, we were thinking it would be nice to have the ability to display a screen/app from someone's PC on the wallboard.

The challenge here is that this is not a touch-screen device; all we have is the [Pivos IR remote](http://imageshack.us/a/img442/2210/xiosds3.png). I am looking for a way of:

- Remotely, from one of several workstations, initiate the display -- ideally without any action needed on the Android device, or at least with something simple like a 'Yes/No' confirm prompt that can selected using the Pivos IR remote.
- Ideally once the PC ends the session, the wallboard goes back to Kiosk display. Less ideally, it's easy to return using the IR remote.

This may be a combination several things/apps that need to be done, I am just not sure what they'd be.

---

Remember, I am trying to display something from a PC on the Android device, shared among several people. This means:

- Something that uses Google Accounts for authentication/connection won't work, since this is shared among several people (who likely are logged into their own Google accounts using Chrome)
- I want to mirror the desktop display so it's displayed on the Android-connected TV. I am NOT trying to remotely control the PC from the android, or the android from the PC.